# Exact sequence of total complexes

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm working though Weibel right now, and I'm getting stuck on Exercise 1.3.6:

> If $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is an exact sequence of double complexes, show that $0 \to Tot(A) \to Tot(B) \to Tot(C) \to 0$ is exact.

Obviously each $0 \to A_{p,q} \to B_{p,q} \to C_{p,q} \to 0$ is exact, and I want to just take the direct sum (product?), but I don't think it preserves exactness in an abelian category without AB4, AB4*.

I think there's gotta be more data in the original exact sequence of complexes, that I'm not making use of, but I can't figure out what it is. Any hints?

Comment: In my copy, it says “double complexes **of modules**”, so you have AB4 and AB4*.

Comment: Well, guess I gotta work on my reading comprehension. Thanks! This entire chapter was "yeah, we'll do it in R-mod but it works everywhere because of Freyd (which we haven't proven)", and I guess that threw me off.